# Overload class or?

Tags: c++

I don't understand quite well how to make class/structure which will be like this:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss.str().c_str();
```

I would like to do something similar like this, example:

```
int result = MyAssignFunction(10, 5).AddParametrs();
// or
int result = MyAssignFunction(10, 5).FirstParametr;
```

I cannot name this thats why I cannot find any hints.
The main question is that is even possible or not? Please give me any hint.

Comment: @user2887378 - See here: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `MyAssignFunction` needs to return an object that have an `AddParametrs` member function or a `FirstParametr` member variable.

But you need to be aware of that the object returned by `MyAssignFunction` in your examples is *temporary*. As soon as the expression is over, then it will be destructed.

---

A very ***simple*** example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    int value;

    S(int initial) : value(initial) {}

    S& add1() { value++; return *this; }
    S& add2() { value += 2; return *this; }
    S& addN(int n) { value += n; return *this; }

    int get() const { return value; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Operation = " << S(0).add1().add2().add1().addN(5).get() << '\n';
}
```

The above little dummy program will print

```
Operation = 9
```

The expression that does the "magic" is `S(0).add1().add2().add1().addN(5).get()`. It first creates a (temporary) object of the structure `S` and passes `0` to the constructor. Then on this object we call the member function `add1`, which returns a reference to itself, and on that reference we call `add2`, and so on. Finally we call the member function `get` to get the final value and output it.

As you can see, we can chain any number of function calls and in any order.

The above is just a very simple example, that allows the object to chain calls on itself. A member function can return another object (or reference to), and you can then chain calls to member function of that object. That is what you are seeing in your `stringstream` example: The `str` function returns a `std::string` object, and you call `c_str` on that `std::string` object.

Comment: Or you can return a reference to an object stored inside the class.

Comment: Thanks, but how to design class like that, could you show me explain?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg That's what I was looking for, but I want to change return type of these functions, is that possible? For example I want different return types as GetInteger, GetCharacter, etc. Thanks

Comment: @user2887378 Only the *last* function in the chain can return anything other than an object (or reference to itself). It's the returning of object or object references that allows you to chain calls like that.

Comment: This concept is also sometimes called "method cascading" to differentiate between a simple chain of method calls on temporary return values (chaining) and actually chaining together multiple method calls on the same object (cascading).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for *method chaining* meaning that you can reuse the output of a function call as if it were the object your function was called upon, all you need to do is return `*this`. Therefore your return value should be of the class type you are trying to implement method chaining on. To avoid an unnecessary invocation of the copy constructor, you should also return by reference. Here is a little example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
  A& foo(){
    return *this;
  }
  int bar(){
    return 3;
  }
};

int main(){
  A a;
  std::cout << a.foo().foo().foo().foo().bar(); //prints 3
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for something similar like this but I want to call another function, for example: AssignFunction(10, 5).subtract() something like this

Comment: @user2887378 adapted my answer